# Pandas cannot import data to MySQL database with brackets in column

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I try to upload data into MySQL database using pandas.to_sql method:

```
df5.to_sql(full_table_name, con=engine, if_exists='append',chunksize=10000)
```

, but I got error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%(Location(LAC))s, %(CI(CI))s,
> ...
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)

When I check sql server logs, I found this:

```
8 Query INSERT INTO kpi_d_ho (`index`, `Start Time`, `End Time`, `Location (LAC)`, `Cell (CI)`, `Node(Id)`, `Number of TD`) 
VALUES (0, '2020-12-01 00:00:00', '2020-12-02 00:00:00', %(Location (LAC))s, %(Cell (CI))s, %(Node(Id))s, 0)
```

I checked dataframe, is it ok - all rows contain numbers value (not a column name).
Looks like pandas sent to MySQL column name instead value. when I delete brackets in column name - my script work successfully, so why doesn't it work with columns which contains bracket?

Comment: the location CELL and node are not filled woth data, only the the column name, so you have to check that

Comment: I would avoid special characters like parentheses and spaces for table names and columns. Then the named parameters can work. Plus querying is easier.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved by adding parameter **paramstyle="format"** into create_engine function.
It was:

```
    engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://xxx@xxx/xxx', echo=False, pool_recycle=3600)
```

Now it:

```
    engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://xxx@xxx/xxx', echo=False, pool_recycle=3600, paramstyle="format")
```